# ExtJs TreeGrid with checkable nodes

Tags: extjs, treegrid

If it's possible to have a `TreeGrid` with checkable nodes, how could I create that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [an example](http://www.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/check-tree.html) of a basic checkable tree widget.

As of Ext 4.0, there is now official [TreeGrid](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/treegrid.html) support. Combined with the still-supported [checked](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface-cfg-checked) config when supplied with your tree's node data, it is easy to create a checkable TreeGrid.

Comment: Yes, this is simple checkable tree panel without columns.

Comment: Generally I would agree with you, but why rewrite an existing example that already perfectly illustrates the OP's question?  As a side note in this case, while the link still works today, any code I would have written in June 2010 (almost 2.5 years ago) would definitely be out of date and no longer working as the 4.0 version of Ext would have broken it.